# Columns in PowerBi showing data in power query but not in dashboards

Tags: powerbi, etl, powerquery, business-intelligence

I am facing an issue in power bi the columns in power query shows data exactly what it needs to be but when I close and apply the data of certain columns is just BLANK it does not show, moreover the data in lat long columns does not show decimals just whole numbers. Moreover, I have tried to refresh tables several times bu the problem persists. I have ann underlying BIG DATA solution, the data is correct there but dashboards seem to act weird any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked data types? You should give us more details about data model, maybe some sample data, and what results do you expect.

Comment: it was data types issue resolved thanks for the help !